# PHP dynamically create CSV: Skip the first line of a CSV file

Tags: php, html, csv, fgetcsv

I am trying to import a CSV file.  Due to the program we use, the first row is basically all headers that I would like to skip since I've already put my own headers in via HTML.  How can I get the code to skip the first row of the CSV?  (the strpos command is to cut off the first field in all the rows.)

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("ptt.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
           $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    if(strpos($data[$c], 'Finished') !== false) {
    $c++;
echo "<TR> <TD nowrap>" . $data[$c] . "</ TD>"; }
    Else{
        echo "<TD nowrap>" .  $data[$c] . "</ TD>";
        }
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As you are keeping track of the row number anyway, you can use `continue` to skip the rest of the loop for the first row.

For example, add this at the start of your while loop (just above `$num = count($data)`):

```
if($row == 1){ $row++; continue; }
```

There are other ways to do this, but just make sure that when you continue, `$row` is still being incremented or you'll get an infinite loop!

Answer (score 74):

Rather than using if condition for checking whether it is the first row, a better solution is  to just add an extra line of code before the line from where the while loop starts as shown below :

```
....
.....
fgetcsv($handle);//Adding this line will skip the reading of th first line from the csv file and the reading process will begin from the second line onwards
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
.......
.......
```

It is just as simple......

Comment: @dkar , `fgetcsv` parses the first line ( header ) and returns an array with those columns. Implicitly, the file pointer is now on the 2nd row.

Comment: This answer help me. My code is being created with  header either 0 or 5th or 6th line. It's dynamic. With this method I iterate the file dynamically with a while whenever I need to find the header I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the following lines of code

```
$flag = true;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
//your code for insert
}
```

Having the flag variable as true and setting it to false will skip the first line of the CSV file. This is simple and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

put this inside your while loop:

`if ($row == 1) continue;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the body of the `while` loop above the `$row++;`:

```
if ($row == 1) {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
while (($fields = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $count++;
    if ($count == 1) { continue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
$count = 0;

while(! feof($file))

      {

          $entry = fgetcsv($file, 0, ';');

          if ($count > 0) {
          //skip first line, header


          }

      $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional Read  between the file open stmt and beginning of the while loop is the simplest method but if the file doesn't have a header record you will lose the 1st rec

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

use this code

```
// mysql hostname
$hostname = 'localhost';
// mysql username
$username = 'root';
// mysql password
$password = '';

if (isset($_FILES['file']))
{   

// get the csv file and open it up
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
//$handle is a valid file pointer to a file successfully opened by fopen(), popen(), or fsockopen(). 
$handle = fopen($file, "r"); 
    try { 
    // Database Connection using PDO
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=clasdb", $username, $password);
    // prepare for insertion
    $STM = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO statstrackertemp (ServerName, HiMemUti, AvgMemUti, HiCpuUti, AvgCpuUti, HiIOPerSec, AvgIOPerSec, HiDiskUsage, AvgDsikUsage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ? )');



        if ($handle !== FALSE) 
        {
            // fgets() Gets a line from file pointer and read the first line from $handle and ignore it.   
            fgets($handle);
            // created loop here
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
            {
            $STM->execute($data);
            }       

            fclose($handle);

        }

    } 
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die($e->getMessage());
    }

echo 'Data imported'; 

}
else 
{
echo 'Could not import Data';
}

?>
```