# Wordpress CSV import encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I have a CSV file with data generated by myself in UTF-8 (no BOM) encoding. If i try to upload this data by script (simple reading file and mysql queries, works well), the result is not what i should expect, for example:

```
wnętrza
wnÄ™trz
```

All files scripts etc. are UTF-8 (no BOM), wordpress tables are utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci. I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I am missing some parts. Is data stored in database correctly?

Comment: try below answer and try to use parseCSV method. git.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588731/when-import-csv-skip-header-or-first-row/43589411#43589411

Comment: no, encoding is wrong in database, still all files are utf-8 and tables are  utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci