# Removing first line of CSV in PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I have written PHP code to get values from a CSV file, containing my netflix viewing history, so that I may put into a database. My code is:

```
<?php /* The idea will put my Netflix viewing history into a database */
$history     = fopen("netflix.csv", "r");
while($row    = fgetcsv($history, 1000, ","))
{
    $title = explode(":", $row[0])[0];
    $watch = explode("/", $row[1]);
    echo "I watched {$title} on {$watch[2]}-{$watch[1]}-{$watch[0]}<br>";
}
print_r($items);
?>
```

The reason I am using a while loop is to loop over each line in the CSV file but, when I echo it out to see what I get, I find that I am getting the first line. How do I go about removing the first line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip the first line of a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901113/skip-the-first-line-of-a-csv-file)

Comment: visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072015/remove-line-from-csv-file

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372730/skip-first-line-of-fgetcsv-method-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `fgetcsv` one more time before the loop starts.